# A missing name, ReferenceError in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, superglobals

I've been working during the last 4 weeks in a multiplayer game based on NodeJS and Express. The game has a few different classes inside the /lib/ folder.

So, let's focus on 2:

- Game.Js
- Player.Js

The problem I'm having is that I can't call a method of game, from the Player.Js, meanwhile is possible to call methods of Player.Js from Game.Js.

As the file Bullet.Js is triggering a respawn method from Player.Js:

```
players[i].respawn();
```

I thought I could execute a game method from Player.Js as well... So far I can't come up with a solution.

```
var player = game.all_player_info(socket.id);
            ^
ReferenceError: game is not defined
at Player.damage (C:\Users\...\Desktop\dos\...\lib\Player.js:319:21)
at Bullet.update (C:\Users\...\Desktop\dos\...\lib\Bullet.js:98:18)
at Game.update (C:\Users\...\Desktop\dos\...\lib\Game.js:199:64)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\...\Desktop\dos\...\server.js:751:8)
at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

**Files:**

```
https://github.com/penumbragames/tankanarchy/blob/master/lib/Player.js
https://github.com/penumbragames/tankanarchy/blob/master/lib/Game.js
https://github.com/penumbragames/tankanarchy/blob/master/lib/Bullet.js
```

Same happens if you try to use the socket.io... it works well on Game.Js, but it seems out of scope from Player.Js or Bullet.Js.

I'm obviously new to Node... but:

**1. Is there any way to call Game methods from Bullet.Js or Player.Js?**
2. Is there any way to use socket.emit from the same?

**Goal:**

Find a way to send information to the chat when an event happens on bullet.Js.

Additionally, can anyone suggest a good visualization software / application charting to map the classes, and methods?

Kind regards!!
Chris,

Comment: in terminal.
`npm install gamejs

npm install player.js`

Comment: Have you imported game before calling?

Comment: Yeap, I did, seems like everything is happening inside a game.update loop, so I moved the methods from Bullet and Player directly inside Game... it works that way, of course after adapting the methods, but I wonder why it doesn't work the other way around.

Comment: Relevant code to a question must be pasted directly into the question and formatted properly as code.  Putting code that is required to understand the question only in external links is not permitted here.  This is because external links have a habit of disappearing or getting modified over time rendering the question useless as any sort of lasting reference on the particular type of problem being explored.